# Why am I getting a null output by simply changing the output activation layer?

Tags: python, keras

It works fine like this:

```
def make_model(layers, neurons):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=15, activation='sigmoid'))
    for l in range(layers - 2):
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(14, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model
```

but it breaks like this (see activation of output)

```
def make_model(layers, neurons):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=15, activation='sigmoid'))
    for l in range(layers - 2):
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(14, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model
```

with this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\birdm\OneDrive\Desktop\ai\mancala\libs\generate_train_batch.py", line 82, in play_one_game
    history[whos_turn]['before'].append(targets[choice])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

Why am I getting a null output by simply changing the output activation layer?

Comment: Is model construction giving you error.? Or later trying to train the defined model throws the error.?

Comment: The error points to code that is not in the question.

Comment: @SreeramTP It's after compile, but before training. It's just a simple invoke.

Comment: so `model = make_model(layers, nuerons)` gives error.?